# Запись в битов файл

Tags: python, файлы, битовые-операции, сжатие

Каким образом можно записать последовательность битов (кодов Хаффмана) в файл, чтобы потом можно было однозначно считать их?

Например, при вот такой последовательности битов:

```
1100000001010
```

При делении по 8 бит, в файл записывается:

```
11000000 1010
```

Тоесть теряется старший бит. На Python у меня имеется такой код, который разбивает строку с "1" и "0", на числа по 8 бит

```
l = []
for i in range(0, len(s), 8):
    l.append(int(s[i:i+8], 2))

fout = open("otput.txt", "wb")
fout.write(bytearray(l))
fout.close()
```

Comment: Посмотрите, может это: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887506/convert-python-byte-to-unsigned-8-bit-integer    и  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067813/convert-ascii-character-to-signed-8-bit-integer-python

Comment: В файл можно писать только байтами, ваши "1100000001010" не содержат целого числа байт и запишутся они в файл явно не так. Потеря старшего бита у вас в чем выражается?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, в файл записываются числа вот так 11000000 01010, при этом 0 исчезает и при считывании мы имеем 11000000 1010

Comment: @inceon если вы пишете туда символы - при чем тут запись битов, казалось бы...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, я записываю код символа (число), а числа соответственно представляются битами

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы преобразовать строку из нулей и единичек в байты, которые можно записать в файл:

```py
>>> bitstring = '1100000001010'
>>> n = int(bitstring, 2)
>>> n.to_bytes((n.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big')
b'\x18\n'
```

[Также легко можно обратно преобразовать (байты в биты) и/или использовать код, который работает на Питоне 2/3 одновременно.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7396849/4279)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась добавлением "0" в начало строки битов, пока длина строки не будет кратна 8.

```
00011000 00001010
```

При считывании просто читаем числа и добавляем в начало те же 0, пока количество не достигнет 8